# how to set modal visible according to id?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a map() data each of which has touchableopacity that should set the state of modal visible to true, but am unable to do it.
Could anyone let me know a way to set the state according to id?

ParentComponent:

```
export default function ExpandedVaccineComponent(props) {
  const {navigation} = props;
  const [note, setNote] = useState({});
  const [addNoteText, setAddNoteText] = useState('');
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [selectedItem,setSelectedItem]=useState(null);
  const [demo, setDemo] = useState(false);
  let id = props.id;
 
 
 
 
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        elevation: 3,
        margin: '2%',
        borderRadius: 5,
      }}>
      
    
          <View style={{marginTop: '2%'}}>
            {props.item.vaccine_list.map((i) => {
              return (
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}>
                      <Icon name="calendar" size={15} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <View>
                      <Modal
                        animationType="fade"
                        transparent={true}
                        visible={modalVisible}>
                        <View
                          style={{
                            flex: 1,

                            justifyContent: 'center',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            borderRadius: 20,
                          }}>
                          <CalenderModal
                            item={props.item}
                            modalVisible={modalVisible}
                            item={i}
                            id={id}
                          />
                          <View
                            style={{
                              flexDirection: 'row',
                              backgroundColor: '#fff',
                              alignItems: 'center',
                              justifyContent: 'center',
                              width: '72%',
                            }}>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                              style={{
                                flex: 1,
                                borderTopColor: '#C0C0C0',
                                borderTopWidth: 1,
                                borderRightColor: '#C0C0C0',
                                borderRightWidth: 1,
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                padding: 10,
                              }}
                              onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}>
                              <Text
                                style={{
                                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                  fontSize: 17,
                                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                                  color: '#2D7AFA',
                                }}>
                                Cancel
                              </Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                              style={{
                                flex: 1,
                                borderTopColor: '#C0C0C0',
                                borderTopWidth: 1,
                                borderLeftColor: '#C0C0C0',
                                borderLeftWidth: 1,
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                padding: 10,
                              }}>
                              <Text
                                style={{
                                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                  fontSize: 17,
                                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                                  color: '#2D7AFA',
                                }}>
                                Save
                              </Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                          </View>
                        </View>
                      </Modal>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{marginLeft: '10%', width: '30%'}}>
                      <View>
                        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                          <Text
                            style={{
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: '#000',
                            }}>
                            {i.name}
                          </Text>
                          <Text
                            style={{
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              color: '#000',
                              opacity: 0.5,
                            }}>
                            (Dose{i.dose}/3)
                          </Text>
                        </View>

                        <Text
                          numberOfLines={2}
                          ellipsizeMode="tail"
                          style={{
                            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                            fontSize: 14,
                            lineHeight: 14,
                            color: '#000',
                            opacity: 0.5,
                          }}>
                          {i.protects_against}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{marginLeft: '30%'}}>
                      <Text>{i.child_vacc_status.text}</Text>
                      <Text>16 Aug,2020</Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </View>
              );
            })}
            
                </View>
             
    </View>
  );
}
```

CalenderModal component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';
import axios from 'axios';
import {ROOT} from '../../../ApiUrl';
export default function CalenderModal(props) {
  const [date, setDate] = useState('2016-05-15');
  const [vaccinatedOn, setVaccinatedOn] = useState(null);
  const [reminder, setReminder] = useState(1);
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(null);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(null);
  const reminderSet = () => {
    setReminder(6);
    setToggle(6);
  };
  const vaccinationSet = () => {
    setVaccinatedOn(1);
    setToggle(1);
  };
  const data = props.item;
  const id = props.id;

  const SaveData = () => {
    let url = `some url`;

    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: {
        child_id: id,
        event_date: date,
        status: toggle,
        vaccine_id: data.id,
      },
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log('RES', res);
        if (res.data.code == 200) {
          navigation.navigate('consultationHome', {res: res});
        }
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('ERR', err);
      });
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.modalView}>
        <Text>{props.item.name}</Text>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            marginTop: '5%',
          }}>
          {reminder == 6 && toggle == 6 ? (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Icon
                name="circle"
                size={17}
                color="pink"
                style={{marginTop: '2%', paddingRight: '1%'}}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  fontSize: 17,
                  color: '#000',
                }}>
                Set reminder
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ) : (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}
              onPress={() => reminderSet()}>
              <Icon
                name="circle-o"
                size={17}
                color="#000"
                style={{marginTop: '2%', paddingRight: '1%'}}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  fontSize: 17,

                  color: '#000',
                }}>
                Set reminder
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
          {vaccinatedOn == 1 && toggle == 1 ? (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Icon
                name="circle"
                size={17}
                color="pink"
                style={{marginTop: '2%', paddingRight: '1%'}}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  fontSize: 17,

                  color: '#000',
                }}>
                Vaccinated on
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ) : (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}
              onPress={() => vaccinationSet()}>
              <Icon
                name="circle-o"
                size={17}
                color="#000"
                style={{marginTop: '2%', paddingRight: '1%'}}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  fontSize: 17,

                  color: '#000',
                }}>
                Vaccinated on
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        </View>
        <DatePicker
          style={{width: 200, marginTop: '5%'}}
          date={date}
          mode="date"
          placeholder="select date"
          format="YYYY-MM-DD"
          minDate="2016-05-01"
          maxDate="2016-06-01"
          confirmBtnText="Confirm"
          cancelBtnText="Cancel"
          customStyles={{
            dateIcon: {
              position: 'absolute',
              left: 0,
              top: 4,
              marginLeft: 0,
            },
            dateInput: {
              marginLeft: 36,
            },
            // ... You can check the source to find the other keys.
          }}
          onDateChange={(date) => {
            setDate(date);
          }}
        />
        {console.log('DATE', date)}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalView: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 20,
  },
  
});
```

Any suggestion would be great, please let me know if anything else is required for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try setting up your onPress similar to the RN documentation for TouchableOpacity (https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity.html you also may want to consider switching to Pressable for future proofing purposes). You can do

```
const onPress = () => setModalVisible(true);


<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
```